# Python regex: how to do a negative lookahead with a string which don't start immediately?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax :

> *(?!...)*
>   Matches if *...* doesn’t match next. This is a negative lookahead assertion. For example, *Isaac (?!Asimov)* will match *'Isaac '* only if it’s not followed by *'Asimov'*.

But what to do if there is one or several words between *Isaac* and *Asimov*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Isaac(?!.*Asimov)
```

Use a negative lookahead for any sequence of characters ending in Asimov. `[\s\S]` or the `DOTALL` flag may be appropriate if you want to include newlines in the `.`.

Comment: Just one extra : How I can ignore the case for Asimov, while staying case sensitive for Isaac?

Comment: @user2284570 `"Isaac(?!.*[Aa][Ss][Ii][Mm][Oo][Vv])"`